# Best way to reattach rubber stripping around windshield

Tags: windshield

The rubber stripping around windshield has came loose some of passenger side of 2008 Ford F-150. It has come loose on top only and roughly a couple foot area. It can be pushed back in place but comes back loose after driving. Windshield was replaced roughly 5 years ago.  In pic, it had already been pushed down into slot.What is best way ( adhesive) to keep in place?[image]

Comment: Who replaced the windshield? Most places like Safelite have a lifetime warranty on their installs. You might want to check.

Comment: It was a local company. I don’t remember the name, so I’d have to check my records. Hopefully, they are still in business.

Answer (score 1):

Any automotive windshield shop can reattach the strip.  My local shop fixed one on one of my cars and did not charge.  It took them less than 5 minutes.  While it was being done, I ran next door and bought them donuts.

There are sealants and there are adhesives, and they will know which to use.  Window mounting systems vary.  You likely need an adhesive, and the material will need to be cleaned just prior to application.

On a similar note, many exterior rear view mirrors are held on with urethane adhesives.  Again, visiting the people who have a urethane applicator, and not having to get large tubes for a small job, makes lots of sense.  Again the local shop does them as a courtesy, and in 30 or 40 years I have never paid for a external mirror reattachment.